# unable to set year range in mui x date picker i.e. from 2022

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, react-datepicker

I just wanted to show years from 2022 in mui-x date picker [image: here is the link of sample year range]

```js
 <DatePicker
                  open={isStartDateOpen}
                  error={false}
                  onOpen={() => setIsStartDateOpen(true)}
                  onClose={() => setIsStartDateOpen(false)}
                  value={startDate}
                  inputFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
                  closeOnSelect
                  disablePast
                  // yearRange="-10 : +10"
                  // yearRange="1950:2013"
                  // shouldDisableYear={() => }
                  onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setStartDate(newValue);
                  }}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      fullWidth
                      {...params}
                      error={false}
                      onClick={() => setIsStartDateOpen(true)}
                    />
                  )}
                />
```

Any Solution that i can show only years from 2022 to 2040 or something like that. as yearRange is not exist in this library

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your stylesheet to remove disabled years

```
.PrivatePickersYear-root.has(.PrivatePickersYear-yearButton.Mui-disabled) {
    display: none;
}
```